# Render a TextField in admin as file upload widget

Tags: django, django-admin

Is it possible to render a `TextField` in the Django admin, as a file upload widget and set the `TextField`'s content to the content of said uploaded file?

Bonus points if it's possible to have both.

Comment: By file upload do you mean a text file? And have the content of the text file inserted into the text field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A widget renders form elements. I would just use the Django Admin's [save_model()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model). Something like this (untested):

```
# models.py
class Article(models.Model):
    text_file = models.FileField()

# admin.py
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.text_file = request.FILES['text_file']
        obj.save()
```